# How to Compare Date in linq to entity query without datetime

Tags: wpf, linq-to-entities

```
 var query = _context.POS_ItemPriceListMaster.Where(c => c.FromDate >= FromDate && c.ToDate <= FromDate).Select(t=> t.ItemPriceListMasterID);
        var query2 = from c in _context.POS_ItemPriceList
                         where query.Contains(c.ItemPriceListMasterID)
                         select c;
```

I want to do this but there are no result in query although there are data with from date 
In database field is datetime

Comment: Are you sure your query is right?

Comment: condition c => c.FromDate >= FromDate && c.ToDate <= FromDate looks wrong to me. I think c.ToDate might be needed to compare with ToDate. It might be like c => c.FromDate >= FromDate && c.ToDate <= ToDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `c.FromDate` and `c.ToDate` are dates without time information and `FromDate` is a date with time information.

To fix your query, remove the time from `FromDate`:

```
var fromDateWithoutTime = FromDate.Date;

var query = _context.POS_ItemPriceListMaster
                    .Where(c => c.FromDate >= fromDateWithoutTime
                                && c.ToDate <= fromDateWithoutTime)
                    .Select(t=> t.ItemPriceListMasterID);
```

Comment: var query = _context.POS_ItemPriceListMaster.Where(c => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.FromDate) >= FromDate.Date && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.ToDate) <= FromDate.Date).Select(t => t.ItemPriceListMasterID); Now i use this but its also not work

Comment: @nadeemaamir: Than you don't have data for the date specified by `FromDate`.

Comment: `fromDate` must be _between_ `FromDate` and `ToDate`, so the `<=` and `>=` must be swapped.